# custom Font is not loading in ionic framework

Tags: font-face, ionic-framework

I want to apply Open Sans font in my Ionic Project. I have use this code inside my SCSS folder where my custom scss file (settings.sccs and other scss files) are located (**demoProject\scss_setting.scss**)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url('../www/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../www/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../www/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../www/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../www/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: 200;
}
body{
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

fonts are located here(**demoProject\www\fonts**)

and try to apply on whole body but console of the browser is showing

```
 GET http://localhost:8100/www/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff 
:8100/www/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.ttf:1
GET http://localhost:8100/www/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.ttf
```

Answer (score 17):

I believe you're going too far back in the directory chain.

I think you want something more like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: 200;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

Here is a tutorial for adding Font Awesome into your project, which is a custom font:

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/use-font-awesome-glyph-icons-ionicframework/

Let me know if that helps you.

Regards,

Comment: you are everywhere when i'm looking for some solution about ionic. Great Job!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Comment: Thanks Nic, was trying for a couple of days finally got it working :)

Comment: I think @NicRaboy's article has moved to https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/use-font-awesome-glyph-icons-ionicframework/

Answer (score 1):

Your fonts should be located in
**demoproject/www/lib/ionic/fonts**

and then referred to from the css (in it's default location **www/css/stylesheet.css** like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: url('../lib/ionic/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../lib/ionic/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../lib/ionic/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../lib/ionic/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../lib/ionic/fonts/opensans-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: 200;
}
body{
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```